# Get display name of document Author with Google Docs API?

Tags: java, google-docs

I have to use Google Documents List API for an Android app until I have time to migrate to Drive API.

I want to get the First and Last name of the Author of a Document that is shared with me.

Currently I'm only able to get the username of the Author using the method below.

```
// entry is a DocumentListEntry    
String aName = entry.getAuthors().get(0).getName();
```

Is there a property or method I'm missing?  The documentation for the Java Docs API is sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/Person) don't provide a lot of leeway on this.  You might be able to try and tokenize the name, but there's no inherent guarantee a given name has to be made up of >1 part, and I wouldn't recommend that course of action.